# COALESCE is not working in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

When I execute the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE Unsubscriptions (
    Email varchar(80) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Unsubscribed boolean NOT NULL
);
SELECT COALESCE(Unsubscribed, FALSE) FROM Unsubscriptions WHERE Email = 'nnn';
```

I expect that the select will never return NULL value, because there is COALESCE operation that according to PostgreSQL docs returns first NON-NULL value from parameters (FALSE in this case).

However, on my Amazon RDS instance, the code above still returns NULL, even if there is no entries in the table, but it should take the second parameter.

Why does the COALESCE function not return FALSE value?

Comment: Seems to be Amazon RDS specific.

Comment: something is wrong in your question, your column `Unsubscribed`is already not null. which means your select can't ever return a null

Comment: @Aツ It can return NULL if there is no entries in the table matching the criteria. I also tested it in other databases and it works.

Comment: no it does NOT return an empty row. maybe whatever application you use does that. but this has little to nothing to do with the select

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the key to your misunderstanding:

> still returns NULL, even if there is no entries in the table

If there are no rows in the table, there will be no rows in the output of a simple `SELECT`. The `COALESCE` changes the value in a particular column, for a particular row, but it cannot create extra rows.

As others have pointed out, any rows that *are* in the table are constrained to be `NOT NULL`, so the `COALESCE` will not have any effect.

What you are presumably seeing is an *empty set* in the application where you're querying the data, resulting in behaviour similar to a set with a `NULL` in it. Note that an SQL result set with zero rows will still have columns with names and even types (think of them as the headings of an empty grid).

If you want to guarantee that you always have *at least one row*, you could perhaps `UNION` a dummy row onto the results:

```
SELECT Unsubscribed FROM Unsubscriptions WHERE Email = 'nnn'
UNION
SELECT false as Unsubscribed
```

This dummy row will be there as well as any real results, if there are any, so if you didn't the hassle of skipping it in the application code, you'd need a cleverer solution.

Answer (score 2):

This work

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT Unsubscribed FROM Unsubscriptions WHERE Email = 'nnn'), false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Per your post `Unsubscribed` is a `NOT NULL` column as seen below, then there is no point in using `COALESCE()` function at all. At least I don't see.

```
Unsubscribed boolean NOT NULL
```

`NULL` and empty row are two different thing all together. Moreover, if your table empty then the where condition `WHERE Id = 'nnn'` will never meet and and so no any rows will return. Even if you do a simple `select` result would be empty result set. If a column is marked `NOT NULL` then you can never enter a `NULL` value there and so no point in getting `NULL` back.

Comment: If a column is marked as NOT NULL, it doesn't mean result cannot be NULL. Just execute SELECT Unsubscribed FROM Unsubscriptions WHERE Id = 'nnn' on empty table and it will return NULL as there is no entries.

Comment: it will NOT return a single row

Comment: @user1613797, `NULL` and empty row are two different thing all together.

Comment: how does it return an empty row?